# Express JS + React + Parcel + Gzip : Browser keep downloading gz file instead of visit website

Tags: reactjs, express, gzip, parcel

**Update:**

The problem solved by change 「index.html.gz」 to 「index.html」

So how can I serve gziped html ?

---

I need some help !

I have a portfolio website deployed in heroku using React and Express JS as a middleware to serving gzip

For bundling I'm using Parcel and parcel-plugin-compress for create gzip

https://an194-portfolio.herokuapp.com/

Nothing strange happen until I visit other root directly

For Ex:

https://an194-portfolio.herokuapp.com/books

Then .. instead of loading, it downloading gz file , what I'm doing wrong ?

You can test your self by visit my site

Thank you for your attention

My server.js config

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const open = require("open");

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.get("*.js", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + ".gz";
  res.set("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
  next();
});

app.get("*.css", function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + ".gz";
  res.set("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/css");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static("dist"));

app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./dist/index.html.gz"));
});

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}!`);
    open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
  }
});
```

and here's my package json

```js
"main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html --no-source-maps",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

Comment: Can you provide logs when you try to access that url

Comment: here's log from heroku :


heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/books" host=an194-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=b047dd1c-bf51-41c6-aa2e-4a7dec46c853 fwd="126.25.149.12" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=510 protocol=https